# WPF MVVM Implementation

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have just started using `WPF` with MVVM pattern. I had gone through some material related to MVVM.

However, the project I have to work on has an implementation of MVVM that seems very different than what I have read (maybe incorrect as well, not sure).

The implementation has all the Views (controls or windows) implemented as ResourceDictionary where all the controls, in the view are in the "Style" element.

The code behind for such ResourceDictionary have all the DependencyProperty and the Commands (there is no other class for ViewModel). Also, the classes (code behind) some how inherit from the Windows.Controls.Control class.

Is this the correct implementation ? If not what are the reasons that you see that prove this as a wrong implementation.

I may be wrong but the reasons I see are the following:

1. Implementing views as `ResourceDictionary` is not correct and Resources are not for creating custom views.
2. Having minimal code in the code behind is one of the important aspects of MVVM, that allows for loosely coupled architecture.
3. Since all views inherit from Windows.Controls.Control, writing unit test cases for the views would be difficult.

Am I correct or there are some other reasons that this implementation is incorrect (or am I wrong and this can be a way to implement MVVM in `WPF`).

Your views are highly appreciated.

Below is a sample code: (XAML)

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Presentation"
>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FirstControl}">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:FirstControl}">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="490" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneTime}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="TEST TEXT" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>

                        <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand, Mode=OneTime}"
                                        Width="48" Height="30"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Presentation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// View-model
    /// </summary>
    public class FirstControl : Control
    {
        static FirstControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FirstControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FirstControl)));
        }

        public FirstControl()
        {
            CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnCloseCommand);
        }

        private void OnCloseCommand()
        {
            // Write code to close application.
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CloseCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(FirstControl));
        public ICommand CloseCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CloseCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CloseCommandProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

The `DelegateCommand` is a class to allow delegating command logic to methods passed as parameters.

Comment: Post some sample code and XAML and we can tell you what's wrong or right. Otherwise it's only speculations

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with putting Views in the `ResourceDictionary`. The View layer just tells WPF how to draw different application pieces (the `ViewModels`), and how you store the Views doesn't really matter. What is concerning though is if you have application/business logic in the View layer. There's nothing wrong with having UI-specific code-behind your view, however you should not have application logic in the code-behind your View, such as Click commands or application data. That stuff should be in your ViewModels

Comment: @Rachel Well if you don't see any problem, putting dozens of views in only one file, then you don't see problem seeing functions with more than hundreds lines, then you don't see problem having code that is unmaintanable, then you don't see problem of expenential bad code growing like viruses, on ever growing bad code until it just a tumor maintained but hundreds of developers. And then you still don't see problem: you have never seen and you don't care about.

Answer (score 2):

The main point of MVVM is to allow each layer to be fully tested without the need of "higher" layers.

You should be able to test the Model, and in that test you should be able to successfully complete all the tasks required to send and retrieve data from your data store. Your model testing should not require any view or view-model to complete.

You should be able to test your View Model without the need for any UI code or other View level code. Your View Model should be able to logically do everything your application needs to do without any user interraction or UI code. Ideally, you should be able to test your ViewModel using mocked Model classes that provide predictable responses.

Comment: -1: **No** the main point of MVVM is not testing. It is **seperation of responsibilties**.

Comment: @StephaneRolland You and I have different priorities. SoC leads to testable code - for one with a TDD background, SoR means nothing if it isn't testable.

Comment: if responsibilities are not seperated, you know code is not easily mockable, so not testable. So you understand my point of view.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I understand your point of view, just not the downvote. If you have a better answer, then post it.